# How to combine 2 json respinse in one hit from 2 URLs request

Tags: php, json, curl

I have 2 json response from 2 different urls, the first step one if user fill the customernumber with post method to get the billNo value as below:

```
{  
   "Customer":[  
      { 
         "billNo":"1001337"
      }
   ],
}
```

The second one to another url user fill the billNo (got from the first step above) in a form with post method to get details result response like this:

```
{  
   "Billing":[  
      { 
         "billAccName":"John Doe",
         "billAccStatus":"Active"
      }
   ],
}
```

My question is it possible to combine this result with only using first step only fill up the customernumber? Within the expected result is:

```
{  
       "Billing":[  
          { 
             "billAccName":"John Doe",
             "billAccStatus":"Active"
          }
       ],
    }
```

I am using Curl with PHP to get those responses, is there any other way to achieve this, maybe need to insert to the temp DB table first?

Edited add the script.

```
<form class="form-response" method="POST" action="postform.php">
    <h2 class="form-response-heading">get Response</h2>
    <input name="customernumber" class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="phonenumber"customernumber">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Get Response</button>
    </form>



<?php
$customernumber = $_POST['customernumber'];
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/AccountDetails",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS   => "{ \"customernumber\":\"" .$customernumber . "\"}",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=UTF8",
    "api-key: myapikeynumbers",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Update Script:

```
<?php
$phone = $_POST['customernumber'];
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array("customernumber" => $phone);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/AccountDetails",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS   =>  json_encode($data),
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=UTF8",
    "api-key: myapikey",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $result = json_decode($response);
  $billno = $result->Customer[0]->billNo;
  //now here, make your second API call using the Bill Number retrieved from the response

  $billAccNo = $_POST['billNo'];



$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/getBillingDetails",

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"billAccNo\":" .$billAccNo . "}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=UTF8",
    "api-key: myapike",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);



$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}

}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Your expected JSON is not a valid one. You cannot have `"a":"b":[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, can you please suggest how to make this work within the validat json? Should I record to DB first? Thx

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can write code to achieve your task

Comment: I don't think an usage of a DB is needed for your question. But let that point apart and give us a valid expected output. You can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/). Maybe having `billNo`, `billAccName` and `billAccStatus` in the same object is what you want?

Comment: Hi @iArcadia, yes with the first step user filled up the form will got billNo, billAccName and billAccStatus. Been stuck over a week :(

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase, I tried it but no luck.

Comment: @Bireon That's not an answer to my question as I talked about your expected JSON

Comment: @Bireon if you tried something, show us what you did

Comment: Hi @iArcadia, I edited my question what I want to achieved is in one hit the response result is same like on the second step. What I did is, I created two php form with curl so user need to input in two step. I hope to simply this user only put one

Comment: Your question still does not contain a single line of PHP code. Please add what you've tried such that we can see where your code contains an error

Comment: I created two php form with curl so user need to input in two step. I hope to simply this user only put one. Just use the response to the first request as the input to the second. Put it into a variable and then include that variable in the appropriate place in the second request's input data. You can do it all in one PHP script. Have you tried something like that? If so please show it, and explain what goes wrong with it, and then maybe we can help you correct it. If you haven't yet tried, then at least show us how you make the two requests now, and then we can re-write it a bit for you.

Comment: Hi all, this my code so far

For the form https://codeshare.io/adW1JZ

and the php file
https://codeshare.io/Gbq0dv

Thanks for any help

Comment: But without seeing _any_ of your code, no-one is going to sit and create the whole thing from nothing - for one thing we have no idea how these API requests have to be structured, so the best we could give is a generic example of the principle in any case. I would hope by now that this has become clear to you from all the various comments above.

Comment: Please include your code **here** in the question, otherwise your question is liable to be closed as "off-topic" by the moderators (see item 1. on [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). besides, you don't want to make the job of the volunteers here trying to help you any harder than it needs to be. We don't want to go off to multiple separate pages to gather all the info, we want it all here in front of us, [clearly presented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and ready to use. So do future readers of this question who may be seeking similar solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code to perform the second request, where is your attempt to merge the responses?

Comment: The second attempt is quiet same with the first I just change the object name and the urls, and put in one PHP file, but the result split, I have no idea how to combine this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to programatically retrieve the Bill No from the data returned by the first request, and then put it in a variable to be included in your second request. You can do that by decoding the JSON data into a PHP object and then extracting the correct field from it.

I've assumed that you either only ever get one Customer back from the first request, or that you only ever are interested in the first Customer record returned. If that's not the case you'll have to modify the code accordingly.

Also, you haven't provided the code used to run the second request, so I'll have to leave it to you to use the `$billno` variable in a suitable way in that request.

The change occurs in the `else` statement at the bottom of the code, where instead of just echoing the raw response we instead decode it and take the Bill No from it.

```
<?php
$phone = $_POST['customernumber'];
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array("customernumber" => $phone);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/AccountDetails",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS   =>  json_encode($data),
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=UTF8",
    "api-key: myapikeynumbers",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $result = json_decode($response);
  $billno = $result->Customer[0]->billNo;
  //now here, make your second API call using the Bill Number retrieved from the response
}
```

P.S. I also changed your input JSON data to be created reliably using json_encode. Building JSON by hand, even a simple string like this, is potentially prone to failure due to unexpected syntax errors, typos etc - instead used the tools provided to convert a PHP variable with a known-good structure into a valid JSON string in a reliable, repeatable way.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Really appreciate

Comment: @Bireon Hi. Did you succeed with this? Was the answer helpful to you?

Comment: Hi @ADyson, sorry for late response. I tried use your guide, But failed on the second responses, I am still checking any wrong or typo. I will let you know

Comment: Add your code for the second request into your question if you need specific help with that, and let me know

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I updated my question based on your suggestion but the second request return invalid, I think the billaccno not grab by the second request :(. Tried many way so far, but no luck

Comment: $billAccNo = $_POST['billNo']; ...you are still trying to take this from the submitted form data, but it doesn't exist. You have to use the $billNo which I showed you how to take from $result. You wrote it but then didn't use it. It doesn't get into your 2nd request by magic... :-)

Comment: Try CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"billAccNo\":" .$billNo . "}", instead. P.s. I'm surprised you don't have a warm coming out about a missing index in POST. Maybe you've got debug warnings switched off